# How to post data to database using Ajax call in Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a subscribe box :

[image]

My goal is when the user enter the email, I want to save it to my database.

I already know how to achieve this using form post via Laravel.

---

## Form POST via Laravel

```
public function postSubscribe() {

    // Validation
    $validator = Validator::make( Input::only('subscribe_email'),

        array(

            'subscribe_email'  => 'email|unique:subscribes,email',
            )
        );

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to('/#footer')
        ->with('subscribe_error','This email is already subscribed to us.')
        ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    }else{

        $subscribe        = new Subscribe;
        $subscribe->email = Input::get('subscribe_email');
        $subscribe->save();

        return Redirect::to('/thank-you');

    }

}
```

---

Now, I want to achieve this using **Ajax** call to avoid the page load and also  to learn more about Ajax. Here are what I've tried :

---

## Form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/subscribe', 'class' => 'subscribe-form', 'role' =>'form')) !!}

<div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-1">
  <label class="sr-only" for="mce-EMAIL">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" name="subscribe_email" class="form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter email" required>

  <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_168a366a98d3248fbc35c0b67_73d49e0d23" value=""></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></div>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

## Ajax Call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/subscribe',
        type: "post",
        data: {'subscribe_email':$('input[name=subscribe_email]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);

        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

## Controller

```
public function postSubscribeAjax() {

        // Getting all post data

        if(Request::ajax()) {
            $data = Input::all();
            die;
        }

        dd($data);
    }
```

---

## Route

`Route::post('/subscribe','SubscribeController@postSubscribeAjax');`

---

## Result

I keep getting:

> Undefined variable: data

Which mean my `Request::ajax()` is not containing anything? Why is that?

How can I achieve this using an Ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was resolved in Chat**

We had to fix a couple syntax errors and change the input button to a html button so that it would prevent the form from submitting. There are other ways we could have done this, but this worked.

---

So I'm going to address a few things here. Starting from bottom moving on up!!

**Route**

You can do this without the slash.
`Route::post('subscribe','SubscribeController@postSubscribeAjax');`

**Controller**

Your Controller is good enough, but you need to actually display the result from the ajax. We will handle that.

Remove the `die` in your check if there is an Ajax request.

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the form from submitting
      $.ajax({
        url: '/subscribe',
        type: "post",
        data: {'subscribe_email':$('input[name=subscribe_email]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data); // this is good
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Form**

Pretty sure the form is good.

Comment: Oh my god, you're awesome. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. :D

Comment: In my controller, I tried `dd(Request::ajax());` I got `false`, Am I suppose to see true or false ?

Comment: I'm not sure what should I do now,`$data = Input::all();` never get run.

Comment: you should see true when it is an ajax request. So we need to double check something here... Did the page submit using ajax or did it show you a console??

Comment: what do you get with `Request::all()` ??

Comment: I got this : `array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "S3lWmNn6gkkHrYY6nPmupCtrlRqWF6au7b0Mywy7"
  "subscribe_email" => "bunlongheng@outlook.com"
  "b_168a366a98d3248fbc35c0b67_73d49e0d23" => ""
  "subscribe" => "Subscribe"
]`

Comment: also check `Request::isJson()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77226/discussion-between-cayce-k-and-rangerover-js).

Comment: I have 1 quick question. I `json_decode($data)` and try to `var_dump(json_decode($data));` I don't see anything. What is the properway to extract data from my `$data` variable ?

Comment: It is hard to say I don't know which $data you're talking about. i fyou're talkinga bout in your PHP. you can use Request::input('NAME_OF_FIELD') or if you do Request::all() it is an array so you can loop through it with a foreach. **maybe an object, but you can loop through it and get all the stuff as if it were an array laravel is flexible**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "Undefined variable" error is happening in your `postSubscribeAjax` method, it looks like you have a problem with scope. Specifically, when the PHP interpreter gets to the line `dd($data)`, the variable `$data` has not been defined yet.

This is not surprising, since `$data` is assigned inside the block of code following an `if` statement - it is not available outside that block.

You can solve this problem by adding `$data = null;` before the `if` statement, BUT... this is only going to show you that you have a different problem. Here's why:

You're getting an "undefined variable" error. The means that your code is skipping the `if` block (how do I know this? because if it didn't skip it, it would execute the `die` statement and you'd never see the error). This means that your code is not correctly identifying the request as an AJAX request.

What I would do is this: skip the `if` block entirely. Simply get your data and process it.

It's been a while since I looked at this stuff, but IIRC, there is no reliable way to detect AJAX requests. To the server, an AJAX request is just like any other request. Some Javascript libraries (jQuery included, if I'm not mistaken) set a header on the request to identify it as AJAX, but it is neither universally required nor universally detected.

The only benefit to this AJAX detection is to prevent your users from accessing the AJAX URL directly from a browser. And, ultimately, if someone *really* wants to do that, you can't stop them since they can (with a little work) spoof any request.

Comment: Should still be a part of 5, but see documentation for ajax on [4](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)